# How to make anonymizer in python?

Tags: python

I am working on an anonymizer program which sensors the given words in the list. This is what i have so far. I am new to python so not sure how can i achieve this.

```
def isAlpha(c):
    if( c >= 'A' and c <='Z' or c >= 'a' and c <='z' or c >= '0' and c <='9'):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    message = []
    userInput = str(input("Enter The Sentense: "))
    truncatedInput = userInput[:140]

    for i in range(len(truncatedInput)):
        if(truncatedInput[i] == 'DRAT'):
            truncatedInput[i] = 'x'
        print(truncatedInput[i])
```

this is the output i get

```
Enter The Sentense: DRAT
D
R
A
T
```

I want the word to be replaced by XXXX

Comment: What you need `isAlpha` function for?

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)?

Comment: i am gona validate later on so for that purpose i need that function.

Comment: I am trying not to use any inbuilt functions unless there in no way out.

Comment: `if (truncatedInput[i] == 'DRAT')` will never be met, you should check against single letter here.

Comment: Yup that is what i was going to try. thank you

Comment: What's your end goal here? Things like profanity filters are not trivial - you need to detect the words and variations on the words, not to mention potentially needing to track more interesting cases. Check out [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15109/profanity-filter-for-an-mmo-chat) on GameDev. There's also the [Scunthorpe Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) for false positives.

Comment: There are a lot of clXXXic examples of profanity filter mistakes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems with your code:

1. There already exists an `islpha` function; it is a `str` method (see example below).
2. Your `trucatedInput` is a `str`, which is an immutable type. You can't reassign parts of an immutable type; i.e. `myStr[3]='x'` would normally fail. If you really want to do this, you're better off representing your truncated input as a list and using `''.join(truncatedInput)` to turn it into a string later.
3. You are currently looking at the characters in your truncated input to check if any of them equals `'DRAT'`. This is what your first for-loop in `main` does. However, what you seem to want is to iterate over the words themselves - you will need a "chunker" for this. This is a slightly difficult problem if you want to deal with free-form English. For example, a simple word chunker would simply split your sentence on spaces. However, what happens when you have a sentence containing the word "DRAT'S"? Due to such cases, you will be forced to create a proper chunker to deal with punctuations as required. This is a fairly high-level design decision. You may want to take a look at [`NLTK`](http://nltk.org/) to see if any of its chunkers will help you out.

**Examples**:

`str.isalpha`

```
In [3]: myStr = 'abc45d'

In [4]: for char in myStr:
   ...:     print char, char.isalpha()
   ...:     
a True
b True
c True
4 False
5 False
d True
```

strings are immutable

```
In [5]: myStr[3] = 'x'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bf15aed01ea1> in <module>()
----> 1 myStr[3] = 'x'

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Finally, as others have recommended, you're likely much better off using `str.replace` anyways. However, be wary of replacing substrings of non-cencored words. For example, the substring "hell" in the word "hello" does not need to be censored. To accommodate for such text, you may want to use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), a regex substitution, as opposed to `str.replace`.

One additional note, python allows for transitive comparisons. So you can shorten `if( c >= 'A' and c <='Z' or c >= 'a' and c <='z' or c >= '0' and c <='9')` into `if( 'Z' >= c >= 'A' or 'z' >= c >= 'a' or '9' >= c >= '0')`. This, by the way, can be replaced with `if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit()`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use [string.replace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

```
truncatedInput.replace('DRAT', 'xxxx')
```

This will replace the first occurence of DRAT with xxxx, even if it is part of a longer sentence.  If you want different functionality let me know.

Comment: is there a way to do it without using replace? but thank you for the example.

Comment: @Manmohit yes, find() will also work but require an extra line

Comment: @Manmohit no problem, if you require different functionality let me know, i can change the answer

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the characters in a string and comparing them to 'DRAT'. Since that's multiple characters, the comparison always fails. If you want to iterate over the string by word you must first break it into a list of words using str.split() and iterate over the list.