# How to match words in a list with user input in python?

Tags: python

I am working on program which takes user input and replaces the words in a list with 'x'. 
eg is the word is sucks and user input is "this word is sucks". the output should be "this word is xxxxx.

this is what i have so far. how can i access the elements in the list and match with the user input?

```
def main():
    message = []
    words = ['drat','crap','sucks']
    counter = 0
    userInput = str(input("Enter The Sentense: "))
    truncatedInput = userInput[:140]
    sentence =  truncatedInput.split()
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
```

Comment: [Didn't you ask this question last week](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17528976/198633)? You even accepted [my answer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17529393/198633). Please explain how this question is different from that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    final_message = []
    words = ['drat','crap','sucks']
    counter = 0
    userInput = input("Enter The Sentense: ")  # use raw_input if you're using python2.X
    truncatedInput = userInput[:140]
    sentence =  truncatedInput.split()
    for word in sentence:
        if word in words:
            word = 'x' * len(word)
        final_message.append(word)
     print ' '.join(final_message)
```