# Purifier code using if statements and loops

Tags: python

Hi I am working on a purifier program. I had posted similar code earlier and they all work. I am trying a different approach this time.

This is an example of what i want

input  = this is crap
output = this is xxxx

here is the code i have so far

```
def main():
    message = []
    userInput = str(input("Enter the sentence: "))
    for i in userInput:
        if((i=='c' or i =='C') and (i =='r' or i=='R')):
            i = 'x' * len(i)
        message.append(i)
    print(' '.join(message))
```

the code above works if i dont have "and" in the if statment but as soon as i add "and" this is the output i get

```
Enter the sentence: CR
C R
```

where as i want the output as xx. 
how can i achieve that?
thank you for the help

Comment: Do you want just that word - `crap` to be replaced with `xxxx`? If not, what are the rules?

Comment: for now yes but it can be any word. like crap drat suck and so on. given the conditional statment. it should sensor out those words

Comment: @Manmohit Just curious: is there any particular reason you're now trying to do it this way when you've received a far amount of answers in various forms   already?

Comment: @Manmohit you are doing it in a non python c/c++ ish way. learn about string manipulation functions in python (replace, re module, upper, lower, etc.)

Comment: @JonClements i am still new to python so trying every way out. was just curious to see if it works this way. Could you tell me which functions i can use to achieve it? thank you

Comment: as @JonClements asked, I don't see why you are not using anything suggested from your previous question's answers. looks like all the answers to this questions are answered in your previous questions..

Comment: @Manmohit why are you posting the same question again & again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528976/how-to-make-anonymizer-in-python) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645408/how-to-match-words-in-a-list-with-user-input-in-python) ?

Comment: @sandeepraju if you look the solution. they are not the same. I am new to python as i said and i am just trying to make different solutions.

Comment: @Manmohit looks like you did not get the underlying concept but are looking at getting some code to ctrl+C ctrl+P

Comment: @sandeepraju if i had to copy n paste, there are more then enough solutions online for me to copy. I just tried different possible solutions for the same code. i dont see anything wrong with it. Please explain if you do

Answer (score 3):

The condition `if((i=='c' or i =='C') and (i =='r' or i=='R')):` request that `i` is **both** a (capital or not) `C` and `R` ! So it is always false.

Comment: i am trying to make a combination of word CRAP crap. how else can i achieve that?

Comment: `"your answer\nOP's head"`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to loop over the input. Just check whether the string contains "crap" and replace it with "xxxx":

```
import re
crap = re.compile(re.escape("crap"), re.IGNORECASE)
message = crap.sub("xxxx", userInput)
```

If you have a list of multiple strings, you can create a regex for each of them and replace it in the same string with the specific length:

```
import re
message = userInput
for s in forbidden_words:
    word = re.compile(re.escape(s), re.IGNORECASE)
    message = word.sub("x" * len(s), message)
```

Comment: And what about the case, where there are more words to filter out?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `or` instead of `and` there. However, for your given input, you can use the following loop:

```
if i.lower in ('c', 'r'):
    i = 'x'
```

But this code will just add `x` everytime it sees a `c` or `r`, doesn't matter whether they are entered as a part of word `"crap"` or not.

To check for that word, you don't need to iterate over `userInput`, just test against it:

```
userInput = str(input("Enter the sentence: "))
if userInput.lower() == "crap":
    message.append('x' * len(userInput))
```

If your `userInput` is a space separated words, then you would need to `split` it using `userInput.split()`, and test for each word, thus creating the list iteratively.

---

Further, it would be better if you can write a well-defined rule for filtering noises, like having the list of restricted word in a `file`, then read from it, create a `list`, and then checking whether entered word is in that list(this can work as a temporary solution).

Comment: but what if the combination is CrAp CRap CRAP crAP how should i take care of it ? writing out all the combinations of upper and lower would be alot of code so i wanted to a way which could shorten all the possible combinations for the word crap in both upper and lower cases.

Comment: `userInput.lower()` takes care of it. It will convert all of them to `crap`.

Comment: yea thats true actully.

Comment: This is the min spec for OP's question.  The only obvious inprovment would be to provide a list of bad words instead of hardcoding, ie: 'if userInput.lower() in list_of_forbidden_words':

Comment: Well fine. I've no problem with someone downvoting my answer. But for heaven's sake at least comment on what's wrong. Make your vote count. Else it's simply non-sensinal.

Comment: @RohitJain sorry, I was going to comment but was interrupted for a second. I downvoted because you use `is` for comparing equality (as opposed to comparing identity). You might know the difference, but I guess OP doesn't.

Comment: @l4mpi. Ah! that one. Sorry I just edited `in` to `is`. Missed it badly. :(

Comment: I think this won't work correctly because you check the whole string. If it is `"this is crap"` as in the OP's example, the `userInput.lower() == "crap"` won't match.

Comment: @csharpler. Well, I didn't intend to give exact code. I left it out for OP to figure it out. Just gave an idea how to match the words, and what would go wrong with his/her approach.